# How do I import files in Python?

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying to use `pytest` to check a function—here is my code:

```
# src/return_self.py
def return_self(n):
    return n


# tests/return_self_test.py
import pytest

def test_1():
    value = return_self(1)
    assert value == 1
```

How do I require in my `src` file so that I can test it with `pytest`? I have tried a few things:

```
1. import return_self
2. from src.return_self import *
3. import sys
   sys.path.append('../src')
4. import imp
   return_self = imp.load_source('return_self', '/source/return_self.py')
```

I have also tried them with and without `__init__.py` files in the root and `src` directories. But each time, I get some variation on the error `E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'return_self'`. How can I require in my file?

Comment: are `src/` and `tests/` in the same directory?

Comment: @pythad yes they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
# tests/return_self_test.py

import os
import sys
import pytest

sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(sys.path[0], '..'))

from src.return_self import return_self

def test_1():
    value = return_self(1)
    assert value == 1
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I'm confused though—why does python require 5 lines to import a file?

Comment: @adc17, you can import things from directories on the system path, or the current directory, or subdirectories within a package. That why you need to add outer path to your system path in order to make python see your other folders

Comment: Thank you, so is my way of organising tests unusual? If I'm not following the right conventions please let me know.

Comment: @adc17, no, it's a good practice to place all tests in the `tests/` folder and until your module becomes a package, this importing is a little gotcha you need to know

Comment: Thanks @pythad, one last question. Do you know how this code imports the functions it needs without additional lines? https://github.com/AndyLPK247/automation-panda/tree/master/python-testing-101/example-py-pytest

Comment: @adc17, yes, they use `python -m ...` to run module inside the package. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python for a discussion on this topic.

Comment: Thanks, `python -m pytest` is a great solution.

Answer (score 2):

First, you must check that src/ and tests/ are in the same directory, I checked the function importing `return_self` in `return_self_test.py` and this is how:

Testpy search for files with **test_[prefix]** so I recommend changing return_self_test.py to test_return_self.py

```
# src/return_self.py
def return_self(n):
    return n


# tests/test_return_self.py
import return_self

def test_1():
    value = return_self.return_self(1)
    assert value == 1
```

Finally, test in cmd (in the correct path) or Pycharm terminal with the following command:
***py.test -v*** and voila! It's done (:

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you the `setuptools` approach (**which makes your package distributable :D**)

Project files' structure:

```
.
├── sample
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── return_self.py
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── tests
    └── test_return_self.py
```

where the `sample/` directory matches the package's name and also must contain the source.

Minimal **setup.py** file content:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    setup_requires=['pytest-runner'],
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    name='sample'
)
```

Here we are configuring our test environment (you can extend the `tests_require` variable to include more testing requirements).

**setup.cfg** file content:

```
[aliases]
test=pytest
```

And here we specify we want to run the command pytest every time the developer does: `python setup.py test`

**tests/test_return_self.py**

```
from pytest import *

from sample.return_self import return_self

def test_return_self():
     assert return_self(4) == 4
```

**sample/return_self.py**

```
def return_self(n):
    return n
```

So, the next thing to do is to run:

```
python setup.py develop
```

to make your package available (while running the tests). If you're having problems with permission denied issues: append the `--user` option to the previous command to instruct python you wanna use the package without root permissions --in short the package will be installed into userland directories.

And finally run the tests using:

```
python setup.py test
```

Notes:

- By using this approach, you'll be able to alter your project code on the fly (`python setup.py develop` needs to be run just once)
- No ugly statements to inject the source directory into the current python path.

References:

[Integrating with setuptools / python setup.py test / pytest-runner](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#integrating-with-setuptools-python-setup-py-test-pytest-runner)

[Building and Distributing Packages with Setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords)